# Is there a maximum line length for Chrome's CSS parser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm observing some very weird behaviour related to a long CSS rule.

My HTML looks like the following:

```
<section id="mysection" class="modal">...</section>
```

My (sass-compiled) CSS contains the following rules :

```
.modal {
    display: none;
}

somelement, someotherelement, ... #mysection subelement,... #mysection someothersubelement, ... {
    display: block;
}
```

The second CSS rule is 84000+ character-long. Note that it should not affect the `#mysection` element, but only its children.

The desired result is to hide the `#mysection` element. This is correctly achieved in Firefox 37.0.2. In Chrome 42.0.2311.135 the element is visible -- which is incorrect. The developer tools indicate that the `#mysection` element is affected by both rules, but that the second rule takes precedence. However, I can't seem to find the specific portion of the CSS line that affects the section display property.

The section becomes hidden in Chrome whenever I change its ID.

I can also obtain the correct behaviour in Chrome by manually splitting the CSS line in two sections of ~40k characters with identical `display: block`directives. A hypothesis is that the Chrome CSS parser truncates the long line as follows:

```
... #mysection subelement, ...
              ^
              |
          truncate here
```

As a consequence, the `#mysection` element would be affected the `display: block` directive.

Am I making any sense? I feel like I'm losing my mind here.

Comment: More to the point, a rule **that** long? Time to rewrite your SASS. Can you post your SASS rule?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/e424ce8a1d8dca3c4449941ab9ce27d6fb7ef3c8/lms/static/sass/multicourse/_account.scss#L165
It seems to me that a long identifier definition is better than multiple duplicate definitions, right?

Comment: Wow... No you should definitely not create rules that long. Let me guess, you are extending everything? Duplicate rules do not hurt performance like you might think. Assuming you are extending everything, here is a good article on the subject: http://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-sass-extend/

Comment: I understand there are ways to avoid overly long lines. But here I am trying to understand the cause of my problem with Chrome.

Comment: I don't think your theory about truncation is correct. If the line would truncate, it would also throw away the `{` at the end, causing the whole style rule to be invalid. So that's not it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a single css rule contains over 4096 selectors, it creates an overflow on selector specificity. [This is a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481273), and per the thread, there aren't really any plans to fix it

*"...because having a specificity so high on a node is a very far edge-case."*

It's conjecture, but I'm assuming that the root cause of the issue has to do to with a limitation of a 32bit integer somewhere in the css parser, as that 4096 number is incredibly similar to the stylesheet limits in IE6-9. The math behind that issue is explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219161748/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx).

While it may not be helpful to your specific situation, moving the selectors to their own line appears [resolves the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481273#c8).

Comment: This has been plaguing for 5 months. This bug report is a great discovery; good job!